# Master and Slaves in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I know that Hadoop divides the work into independent chuncks. But imagine if one mapper finished handling its tasks before other mappers, can the master program give this mapper a work (i.e. some tasks) that was already associated to another mapper? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on speculative execution [Yahoo Tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html)-

> One problem with the Hadoop system is that by dividing the tasks across many nodes, it is possible for a few slow nodes to rate-limit the rest of the program. For example if one node has a slow disk controller, then it may be reading its input at only 10% the speed of all the other nodes. So when 99 map tasks are already complete, the system is still waiting for the final map task to check in, which takes much longer than all the other nodes.
>   By forcing tasks to run in isolation from one another, individual tasks do not know where their inputs come from. Tasks trust the Hadoop platform to just deliver the appropriate input. Therefore, the same input can be processed multiple times in parallel, to exploit differences in machine capabilities. As most of the tasks in a job are coming to a close, the Hadoop platform will schedule redundant copies of the remaining tasks across several nodes which do not have other work to perform. This process is known as speculative execution. When tasks complete, they announce this fact to the JobTracker. Whichever copy of a task finishes first becomes the definitive copy. If other copies were executing speculatively, Hadoop tells the TaskTrackers to abandon the tasks and discard their outputs. The Reducers then receive their inputs from whichever Mapper completed successfully, first.
>   Speculative execution is enabled by default. You can disable speculative execution for the mappers and reducers by setting the mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution and mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution JobConf options to false, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, but speculative gives the same task to n mappers which is not good for a relatively small cluster, how can we solve the problem of having tasks with different difficulties and thus to let the master program check each mapper if it has finished its tasks or not, if it is the case then we give it a portion of the data that was associated to another mapper !!

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo Tutorial information, which only covers MapReduce v1, is a little out of date, though the concepts are the same.  The new options for MR v2 are now:

mapreduce.map.speculative
mapreduce.reduce.speculative

Comment: but speculative means that the task from the beginning will be given to X mappers and the fastest is the one that will send the answer to the master program, right?
I wanted to inquire about giving some tasks to a mapper X1 then discovering that mapper X2 has finished his work and thus giving him  a portion of the work that was associated to the mapper X1 !!

Comment: Correct, speculative execution only covers the entirety of a map or reduce task.  It cannot divide a task that is already in execution, giving part of its workload to another mapper or reducer.  As far as I know, that feature does not exist in Hadoop.